# jquery how to run a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers

'
i have a javascript function that im trying to trigger and run. here is what i came up so far, but something seems to be wrong:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#fb_login").click(function(){
<!--
function myPopup2() {
window.open( "http://www.page.html", "myWindow", 
"status = 1, height = 400, width = 400, resizable = 0" )
}
//-->
});

$("#fb_login").click();
</script>
<p id="fb_login" onclick="myPopup2()"></p>
```

any ideas?
thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's simpler than you think :-)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myPopup2() {
        window.open("http://www.page.html", "myWindow", 
            "status = 1, height = 400, width = 400, resizable = 0");
    }

    $("#fb_login").click(myPopup2);
</script>

<p id="fb_login"></p>
```

This will bind the popup to a click on the `#fb_login` element. However, if you are trying to run it at once, then just:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myPopup2() {
        window.open("http://www.page.html", "myWindow", 
            "status = 1, height = 400, width = 400, resizable = 0");
    }

    myPopup2();
</script>
```

or simply

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.open("http://www.page.html", "myWindow", 
        "status = 1, height = 400, width = 400, resizable = 0");
</script>
```

is sufficient.

However, you should be aware that `window.open` without user input (like a click) will trigger a popup-preventer in all modern browsers. Some will give a warning, others will ignore your function call altogether, and you programmatically calling `click()` won't change that.

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#fb_login").click(function(){
window.open( "http://www.page.html", "myWindow", 
"status = 1, height = 400, width = 400, resizable = 0" )
});

$("#fb_login").click();
</script>
```

Just take out the inner function. You're declaring a function in the click handler, but you never calling it. Instead, just use the handler to run your code.

Answer (score 1):

No need to once again .click()

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myPopup2() {
window.open( "http://www.page.html", "myWindow", 
"status = 1, height = 400, width = 400, resizable = 0" )
}
</script>
<p id="fb_login" onclick="myPopup2()"></p>
```

its enough!!